# Chapel analog for Fortran do loop increment?

Tags: chapel

Is there a Chapel analog for the Fortran [do loop increment](http://www.tat.physik.uni-tuebingen.de/~kley/lehre/ftn77/tutorial/loops.html)? e.g., Fortran such as:

```
 do i = 0, numprocs, istep ...
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
config const numprocs = 5;
config const istep = 2;
for i in 0..numprocs by istep {
  writeln(i);
}
```

Note that a negative step will iterate over the range in reverse.

More information and examples are available [in the range primer](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/primers/ranges.html).